# How to check for user role when using passport for authentication in node js application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, passport.js

I have an angular 4 application that is supported by node js in the backend.
I have used passport for user authentication.

The application that I am trying to build allows for users with different roles to login to the application.

For example - The application allows users to be of type 'student' or 'recruiter'.

I have successfully setup the authentication model and able to login and logout of the application successfully.

However,one problem that I currently facing is -

If I select the student login link and pass credentials of user who is registered as a 'Recruiter', then the application allows the user to login as passport authentication currently only validates the username and password.

I am looking on how passport would be able to leverage the usertype that is also populated for all usertypes when they sign in to the application.

If a user is registered as a student, but tries to login as a recruiter, then apart from validating the username and password, I need the application to check if the user has the appropriate role to login to the module.

Currently a user registered as a student is able to login as a recruiter and is able to navigate to the recruiter dashboard as passport is only validating the username and password.

**UserModel -**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var User = new Schema({
    usertype:   {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        enum: ['admin', 'student', 'recruiter'],
        default: 'student'
    },
    email:   {
        type: String
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
});

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

**passport login -**

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
  var token = authenticate.getToken({_id: req.user._id});
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.json({success: true, token: token, status: 'You are successfully logged in!'});
});
```

Comment: print req.user , this contail all user info , userType also

Comment: That would not help as even If I know the userType from req.user.usertype object, the same service is used for login by the recruiter as well. I need to be able to compare the usertype information in the request with the usertype information in the response. How can I fetch the user information in the response?

Comment: Just add an additional piece of middleware to your routes that verifies the user role.

Comment: James, Can you provide some pointers on how to go about this middleware code? any code snippets? Thanks in advance

Comment: @svijay.aug12 presumably you're using Express? [Read the docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)